# Construi uma playlist de vídeos em jQuery e está funcionando, porém não como o esperado, onde está o erro?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Sou desenhista industrial (designer e ilustrador) por formação e não sou programador, mas gosto muito de aprender sobre tecnologia e programação. Construi, com ajuda de tutoriais de jQuery na internet, uma "playlist" de vídeos, a idéia básica seria a de clicar em um dos itens abaixo e trocar o vídeo em cima, mudando o SOURCE do IFRAME do vídeo. Está funcionando, a troca acontece ao se clicar, porém o vídeo está abrindo em outra página, ao invés de trocar em cima do vídeo mesmo e na mesma página. O que está errado? Desde já, grato por sua ajuda e um forte abraço.

```css
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        $("#listagem li a").click(function(e) {
    
            e.preventDefault();
    
            $(".video iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    
        });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- PLAYER de vídeo -->
    <div class="video">

       <iframe width="" height="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qdIdPBIF6MU" frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

    </div>

    <!-- LINKS -->
    <ul id="listagem"><li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdIdPBIF6MU&feature=youtu.be" id="aula1">Aula 1 <br/> <h3>Título da aula 1</h3></a></li><li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfh0cpyv6hc" id="aula2">Aula 2 <br/> <h3>Título da aula 2</h3></a></li><li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hFhYjmPfAk" id="aula3">Aula 3 <br/> <h3>Título da aula 3</h3></a></li><li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hFhYjmPfAk" id="aula4">Aula 4 <br/> <h3>Título da aula 4</h3></a></li></ul>
```

Comment: esses links não deveriam ser embed?

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi.

Comment: talvez eu esteja confundindo, mas quando você copia um link do yt pra por no seu site ele não deveria ser :https://www.youtube.com/EMBED/iddoyoutube

Comment: tipo, o seu primeiro do iframe ta nesse padrão, mas os dos links não

Comment: Ele carrega os vídeos só que em outra página. Usei o padrão de incorporação EMBED, conforme você descreveu e também não funcionou, continua abrindo na outra página.

Comment: acabei de testar fazendo exatamente isso aí que eu disse nos seus links e deu certo, tô usando chrome versão 69

Comment: ficou assim : <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rfh0cpyv6hc" id="aula2">Aula 2 <br/> <h3>Título da aula 2</h3></a></li><li>

Comment: Valeu! Obrigado, Lucas! Irei testar.

Comment: se der certo por gentileza sinaliza pra eu deixar como resposta

Comment: Lucas, descobri o que estava errado! Faltaram atributos: NAME no alvo e o TARGET nos links das aulas. Mexi nisso e está funcionando! Valeu, cara, obrigado por sua ajuda!